# Octave - warning: unable to open X11 DISPLAY

Tags: x11, osx, gnuplot, octave

My setup is as follows:

Octave 3.6.4
Mac OS X Mavericks
2009 Macbook Pro

I'm trying to run Octave in Terminal, with gnuplot.  I'm trying to plot matrices in a graph, as part of an online Coursera Machine Learning course.

I'm getting the following error when opening Octave in Terminal:

`warning: unable to open X11 DISPLAY`

I've opened XQuartz, I've set display using `export DISPLAY=:0.0`.

After extensive searching, I thought the problem might be that the X server wasn't running.  I've tried using the command `startx`, although it just hangs on `waiting for X server to begin accepting connections`.. and eventually gives up.

I'm lost - any ideas?

Comment: Don't know what could cause this, but you can try to use the `wxt` terminal.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, that worked a treat.  I reinstalled the +wxt version of gnuplot using MacPort, this answer helped me out too:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13665181/2742630
If you respond as answer I'll mark it as the correct one!
Thanks